# Get info about state of search index via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, search, enterprise-search

I can get info about index state using cmdlet Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus:
[image]

How can I get state of index directly without requesting info about all search components? 
I tried to use properties of component of search topology, but these properties does not include property "State":[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the SharePoint SRx Reports. They were created by Microsoft Search PFEs for this purpose. They go into great detail on all of the components. 
[Office SRx Core Reports](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SRx-Core-SharePoint-Search-d60113e9/)